# bmatrix - buggy? Alternating Color and not completely drawn

Tags: color, matrices

[image]

As you can see, my `bmatrix` is a little bit bugged and I don't know why...

This is the sourcecode:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{d}_x \\
\mathbf{d}_y \\
\mathbf{d}_z \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & {\cos \mathbf{\theta}_x } & { - \sin \mathbf{\theta}_x }  \\
   0 & { \sin \mathbf{\theta}_x } & { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_x }  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
   { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_y } & 0 & { \sin \mathbf{\theta}_y }  \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
   { - \sin \mathbf{\theta}_y } & 0 & { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_y }  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
   { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_z } & { - \sin \mathbf{\theta}_z } & 0  \\
   { \sin \mathbf{\theta}_z } & { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_z } & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}\left( {\begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf{a}_x  \\
   \mathbf{a}_y  \\
   \mathbf{a}_z  \\
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf{c}_x  \\
   \mathbf{c}_y  \\
\mathbf{c}_z  \\
\end{bmatrix}} \right)
\end{equation}
```

Nothing magic inside of my equation. A simple example with `\begin{bmatrix} 1 // 2 // 3 \end{bmatrix}` has the same result and problem...

I'm importing this:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
```

Has anyone seen this problem before? What can I do to solve it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  As it is, the code you provided does not add the colors.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: It gives what I assume to be the intended output for me, have you updated your packages recently?  Also, is this really minimal?  Where are the alternating row colors coming from?

Comment: Hey. Thanks for including my image! I thought about writing the full sourcecode for compiling inside my question, but I'm using a very complex .cls with over 600 lines which has a lot of dependencies... :(

Comment: The template is found on: https://github.com/dmke/thesis-template - maybe this will help?

Comment: I don't understand why `thesis.cls` uses `babel` if it is meant to use xelatex.

Comment: I can't tell you :(

Comment: I guess you are using a `\rowcolors` command from the `xcolor` package.  What is happening is that color is being drawn on top of the left bracket (the right bracket is added afterwards and so not covered).  You will get similar problems with other ams matrices.  The packages aren't really designed to work together.

Comment: and how can I avoid this behaviour? Is it possible to use another color package just for the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

A poor man's trick would be to put the matrices twice, first with the row colors, then without:

```
\documentclass[english]{thesis}
\title{Title}
\geometry{hmargin=25mm}

\rowcolors{1}{yellow}{white}

\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
% Remember environment `bmatrix' in environment `org@bmatrix'.
\let\org@bmatrix\bmatrix
\let\endorg@bmatrix\endbmatrix
% (\RenewEnviron complains with an error, thus \NewEnviron is used
%  and the old meaning of environment `bmatrix' needs to be cleared.)
\let\bmatrix\relax
\let\endbmatrix\relax
\NewEnviron{bmatrix}{%
  \mbox{%
    \edef\BODY{%
      $\noexpand\m@th\noexpand\begin{org@bmatrix}%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
      \noexpand\end{org@bmatrix}$%   
    }%
    \rlap{\BODY}%
    \@rowcolorsfalse
    \BODY
  }%
}   
% Assuming, environment `bmatrix' is not put in \scriptstyle or
% \scriptscriptstyle (subscript, superscript, fractions, ...). 
% Otherwise \mathpalette (or \mathchoice) is needed.
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{d}_x \\
\mathbf{d}_y \\
\mathbf{d}_z \\   
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & {\cos \mathbf{\theta}_x } & { - \sin \mathbf{\theta}_x }  \\
   0 & { \sin \mathbf{\theta}_x } & { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_x }  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
   { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_y } & 0 & { \sin \mathbf{\theta}_y }  \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
   { - \sin \mathbf{\theta}_y } & 0 & { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_y }  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
   { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_z } & { - \sin \mathbf{\theta}_z } & 0  \\
   { \sin \mathbf{\theta}_z } & { \cos \mathbf{\theta}_z } & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}\left( {\begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf{a}_x  \\
   \mathbf{a}_y  \\
   \mathbf{a}_z  \\
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf{c}_x  \\
   \mathbf{c}_y  \\
\mathbf{c}_z  \\
\end{bmatrix}} \right)
\end{equation}  

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The result is not perfect, the colors exceeds the brackets, but at least the delimiters are visible.